# How to monitor incoming emails with specified sender/subject and trigger http request? (Win10)

Tags: windows-10, email, macros

I want to monitor incoming emails for a specific sender and subject line, and trigger an HTTP GET request when detected. I do have an Outlook 2016 VBA macro to do this, but it often fails to trigger so I'm looking for something more reliable which can run on Windows 10.
Can anyone recommend a method (ideally one which doesn't require a software purchase)?